# Use java in Android Studio to place button to RIGHT_OF another widget

Tags: java, android, button, layout, dynamic

I am creating a button dynamically in Android Studio in a class that extends Fragment. I have my button created (btn) and a text that I want to go under that button (appName), but now I want to place the button next to another button that already exists (lets call it btn_2). I am having trouble finding out how to place one widget next to another using Java, and not xml. Here is what I have so far:

```
    public void createButton (BitmapDrawable bitmapdrawable, String applicationName){

    LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    ViewGroup container = null;

    // Get Layout home_fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment);


    // create image button with background as bitmapdrawable
    ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(getActivity());
    btn.setImageDrawable(bitmapdrawable);

    // create textview with applicationName
    TextView appName = new TextView(getActivity());
    appName.setText(applicationName);

    // place new button next to existing button
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);

    // place text under newly created button





    // Put button and text in layout
    rLayout.addView(btn);
    rLayout.addView(appName);
 }
```

Where I am running into errors is:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
```

How do I pass through the ID of the EXISTING button (btn_2), that I want my new button (btn) to be placed next to?

Then, I want to fill in this empty gap

```
// place text under newly created button
```

of how to place my newly created textview (appName) under my newly created btn and under my existing btn_2. (Maybe this will be more straight forward after I figure out how to place one button next to the other.)

Here is my MainActivity. My image and string that I am passing to HomeFragment createButton method are being sent to MainActivity through a socket from another device:

```
// main activity (FragmentActivity provides fragment compatibility pre-HC)
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  MenuFragment.OnMenufragListener {


private Thread repeatTaskThread;
private byte[] byteArray;

// called when the activity is first created
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);


  // Listening for last installed app to create button
  RepeatTask();
 }


 @Override
 public void onMenufrag(Fragment s) {

  // get body fragment (native method is getFragmentManager)
  HomeFragment fragment = (HomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_fragment);

  // if fragment is not null and in layout, set text, else launch BodyActivity
  if ((fragment!=null)&&fragment.isInLayout()) {
     fragment.getView();
  } else {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,HomeFragment.class);
     startActivity(intent);
  }

}


private void RepeatTask()
{
  repeatTaskThread = new Thread()
  {
     public void run()
     {
        while (true)
        {


           try {

              System.out.println("TRY_1");

              Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.26", 5050);

              // Get data sent through socket
              DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

              System.out.println("DataInputStream Started");

              // read data that got sent
              String applicationName = DIS.readUTF();


              // read array data for bitmap


              //Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packagename);
              //System.out.println("icon" + icon);



              int len = DIS.readInt();
              byte[] data = new byte[len];

              DIS.readFully(data, 0, data.length);



              // Convert data to jpeg first then to bitmap (cant convert byte array directly to bitmap)
              YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, 100, 100, null);
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 80, baos);
              byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();

              // Convert to Bitmap
              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);


              // Image to png in file directory

              // STREAM IMAGE DATA TO FILE
              // This is how I know I am correctly getting my png image (no errors here)


              // convert bitmap to drawable
              Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);

              // convert drawable to bitmapdrawable
              BitmapDrawable bitmapdrawable = (BitmapDrawable)d;
              Log.d("tag_name", "BITMAP Drawable" + bitmapdrawable);

              // Create file to stream bitmpadrawable
              FileOutputStream fosIcon = openFileOutput(applicationName + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

              // compress bitmapdrawable into png and write to file that was just created
              bitmapdrawable.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fosIcon);
              InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(applicationName + ".png");

              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

              // GET FILE DIRECTORY

              File imageFile = new File(getFilesDir(), applicationName + ".png");


              HomeFragment createbutton = new HomeFragment();
              createbutton.createButton(bitmapdrawable, applicationName);
              Log.d("tag_name", "Entered Home Fragment");


              socket.close();


           } catch (Exception e) {


              System.out.println("Exception is "+e.toString());

           }



           try
           {
              // Sleep for 5 seconds
              Thread.sleep(5000);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     };
  };
  repeatTaskThread.start();
 }

 }
```

Here is my xml for HomeFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"
    >


</RelativeLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the view id to make your view `right of` . Try -

```
TextView appName = new TextView(getActivity());
int id = 1001;
appName.setId(id);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, id);
```